# Submit html form with results in webview

Tags: android, forms, post

If I have a HTML form like this:

```
<form action="form_action.php" method="post">

First name: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br />
Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br />

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And then I want to fill the fname & lname then like "press" the submit button programmatically and after that show the form_action.php with the post's in a webview.

And just so you know, I can't change the form, b'cause it's not my site I'm using.
Is that possible?
Hope you get it.

Thanks in advance. (Very sorry for bad english!)

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/q/9373103/1321873

Comment: Yeah but I can't figure out how to press the submit button. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You don't need to **press** the submit button, but perform the same operation when button gets pressed - viz., submit the request as an HTTP POST. Read about how HTTP works to know more.

Comment: So what you mean is that I can go directly to form_action.php and post the data there? If so I know but when I do that I only get a white screen.

Comment: Nevermind, got it work'd! Can't share it b'cause the site doesn't show white page anymore! :)