# Is it possible to do http post using Android WebView Api

Tags: android, android-webview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTTP POST response into WebView in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373103/http-post-response-into-webview-in-android)

In my Android Application i want to use View parts in HTML,CSS using Web View.Is it possible to do http post using jquery ajax in this webview API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with

```
WebView webview = findviewbyid(R.id.webview);
byte[] post = EncodingUtils.getBytes("postvar=value", "BASE64");
webview.postUrl("http://www.mysite.com/post", post);
```

Comment: I want to do Http Post from Jquery only.I dont want to Http post from java.is it possible?