# Android webview - cache illegal expires

Tags: android, webview

While loading a specific url in webview , i am getting this warning

08-08 18:41:38.259: E/cache(3195): illegal expires: Thu, 08 Aug 02013 02:25:58 UTC

many times. The result is it takes lot of time to open that url in webview.

What does this warning mean?

Comment: Maybe this is related to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373103/http-post-response-into-webview-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning is coming with emulator only. On device its working fine.