# Passing params in Post method for webview

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I am developing an application which load jsp page in webview.It send the parametres to the jsp oage using Post method.I am creating a string of parameter & passing to post method like this

```
w1.postUrl(protocol +"://"+host_ip+":"+portnumber+"/"+FOLDER+"/folder/data.jsp", EncodingUtils.getBytes(params, "BASE64"));

params="?username="+uname+"&password="+password;
```

Now i have two questions

1. Do i need to pass the '?' in params for POST method if i don't pass '?' then i get error.
2. I get value null for password

Comment: Because i am loading webview in android

Comment: okay, but then the problem is not related to jsp (you'd have it with any server side technology), and you probably mean android-webview instead of webview.  I'll change the tags for you.

Comment: Create an HttpPost request object and use the setParameter() method

Comment: can you provide some code for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an HttpPost object to set the paramters:

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(blobUploadURL);
    String param="param";
    httpPost.setParameter("parameter, param);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    }
```

Comment: but i am sending post param from webview

Comment: Check these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373103/http-post-response-into-webview-in-android
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452289/how-to-make-post-requests-with-webview